# Data validation dropdown

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I am not good with VBA. Thanks to Google, helping a lot to my project. I had added data validations through "Data and data validation, then list" but while doing copy paste, I am missing data validation dropdowns. So I want to update dropdown list through VBA so that even if you do copy paste, I will not lose dropdown. I want to add data validations in my "Data" Sheet from "Info" sheet. In Info sheet, I have to defined some range. I got some code from Google and it is working fine only in one column, but how can I give define range instead of A1:A5. Like that, I want to add somany data validation in each column of "Data" Sheet from "Info" Sheet.

```
    Private Sub main()
    'replace "A" with the cell you want to insert the dropdown list
    With Sheet2.Range("A2:A10").Validation
   .Delete
   'replace "=A1:A5" with the range the data is in.
   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
   Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5"
   .IgnoreBlank = True
  .InCellDropdown = True
  .InputTitle = ""
  .ErrorTitle = ""
  .InputMessage = ""
  .ErrorMessage = ""
  .ShowInput = True
  .ShowError = True
  End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: When adding a Data Validation table from Excel buttons, ensure that the range is tied to a sheet, so when it is copy/pasted, it doesn't replace the appropriate references.  With that, you can copy/paste a Data Validation drop-down menu from sheet to sheet.  As this is a one-time fix, just fix the individual drop-down, then use VBA to paste it wherever.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5"
> ```

This formula needs to refer to the range that supplies the values you want in your validation list. You'll want that to be a *named range*, rather than a hard-coded range address like this.

So if you have a data table, say, `tblData`, and that table has a column, say, `Values`, then you can define a workbook-scoped *name* that points to `tblData[Values]`: name that range, say, `AvailableValues`, and then you can do `Formula1:="AvailableValues"` and your validation dropdown will automatically keep up with whatever `tblData[Values]` contains.

Beyond that, I've no idea what you're asking. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

'' Validation list with scrollable dropdown.
'' * General Sub without hardcoded specific ranges (modular).
'' * No empty cells at the end of each dropdown.
'' * Calculated Source LastRow and validation dropdown combobox LastRow.
'' * Wrapet with NoUpdate YesUpdate subs for fast run.
'' * Wrapet with Unprotect and re-protect subs for Worksheet that is initially protected.
'' See at the end an example of Call of main sub by RunGeneralValidate

Public Sub GeneralValidate( _
ByVal sheetSource As Worksheet, ByVal columnSource As String, ByVal firstRowSource As Long, _
ByVal sheetCombo As Worksheet, ByVal columnCombo As String, ByVal firstRowCombo As Long)

Dim rangeSource As Range
Dim rangeCombo As Range
Dim lastRowSource As Long
Dim lastRowCombo As Long

Call NoUpdate
Call UnprotectAll

   lastRowSource = sheetSource.Cells(sheetSource.Rows.Count, columnSource).End(xlUp).Row
   lastRowCombo = sheetCombo.Cells(sheetCombo.Rows.Count, columnCombo).End(xlUp).Row
   
    Set rangeCombo = sheetCombo.Range(columnCombo & firstRowCombo & ":" & columnCombo & lastRowCombo)
    Set rangeSource = sheetSource.Range("$" & columnSource & "$" & firstRowSource & ":$" & columnSource & "$" & lastRowSource)
    
    With rangeCombo.Validation
        .Delete ''delete previous validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & "'" & sheetSource.Name & "'" & "!" & rangeSource.Address
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = vbNullString
        .ErrorTitle = vbNullString
        .InputMessage = vbNullString
        .ErrorMessage = vbNullString
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    
Call ProtectAll
Call YesUpdate
     
End Sub


Public Sub NoUpdate()
    Application.Cursor = xlWait
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub


Public Sub YesUpdate()
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Public Sub ProtectAll()
' Protect all to dis-allow modifications if locked
'' UserInterfaceOnly Alows VBA code to modify locked cells.

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ProtectStructure
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.ProtectContents = False Then
                ws.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
                    ws.Protect Password:="1234", _
                               Contents:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
                               AllowDeletingColumns:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
                               AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
                               AllowFiltering:=False, AllowSorting:=False, AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
                               DrawingObjects:=False, Scenarios:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
                               
                                If ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowFormattingColumns = False Then
                                   ActiveSheet.Protect AllowFormattingColumns:=True
                                End If
         End If
    Next
End Sub

'Unprotectall to unlock cells and allow modifications
Public Sub UnprotectAll()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    UnProtectStructure
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   If ws.ProtectContents = True Then
        ws.Unprotect "1234"
        ws.Cells.Locked = False
    End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Public Sub RunGeneralValidate()
''Example of running the subs
Dim Info As Worksheet
Dim Data As Worksheet
Call GeneralValidate(Info, "A", 2, _
                     Data, "D", 4)
                     
Call GeneralValidate(Info, "B", 2, _
                     Data, "E", 4)

Call GeneralValidate(Info, "C", 2, _
                     Data, "F", 4)
End Sub
```